# Multiple functions with pointer as argument, false calculations

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I have an numpy-array (arr) of type integer which is passed to a C-function with ctypes. I narrowed it down to a simple example. I have this three functions:

```
int fun(void *arr, void *arr_out){
    fun2(arr,arr_out);
    return(1);
}

void fun2(int *arr, double *arr_out){
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        *(arr_out+i) = calc((arr+i));
    }
}

double calc(int *in){
    return (double)((log(*in)*-0.15)/1.76);
}
```

Do I use the pointers in right way? My outputs looks kind of random. As if the pointer itself is in someway part of the calculation and not the value?

Comment: Why `fun()` does not take a pointer to `int`?

Comment: Please provide the calling code

Comment: What output? `calc` returns a double but `fun2` discards the return value and `fun` returns a constant `1`.

Comment: `calc((arr+i));` this would usually be written as `calc(arr[i])` then calc is a simple `double calc(int in)`, but your syntax is correct.

Comment: Is that the order you have those function in your code? Do you get any warnings?

Comment: @FireLancer Sorry. I changed the code. I write the output to an array, also defined in python.

Comment: @Blaze No I have them in the right order. So each function is defined before the other calls it. Also no warnings at all with.